# import return value from javascript into json file

Tags: javascript, json

Is it doable to import return value from javascript into json file ? I'll be modifying parameters of the json object depending on the value returned by the javascript.

```
var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
               {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
               {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont tested this maybe this work:

With return value i guess you have some function like this:

```
const myFunction = function(){

                   return {'Id':'4','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'};
                              }
```

And with the .push() function you can push your value, in this case the return value is an object, into the array:

```
jsonObj.push(myFunction())
```

Comment: I'm not sure what problem your solution supposed to solve. You might've misunderstood the question. I've got file, say, `one.json` and I need to modify its parameters depending on the result of javascript file, say, `two.js`. So I'm thinking of a way to import the javascript file and use the return value in the json object.

Comment: @mr_incredible I don't think we can import any js file in JSON file. Alternatively, you can import .json file into the javascript file then read/modify its value. even you can write it back to .json file after modifying it if its in node js env.